# How do I add icons to the desktop in 10.04?

Tags: 10.04

I Have setup Ubuntu 10.04 and all I want to know is how to make a desktop top full of icons like Windows?

Comment: huh? right-click and add documents and folders... Can you supply a link to a screenshot highlighting what you are asking?

Comment: -1 Please read the FAQ concerning how to ask. http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

You can put icons on the desktop in the same way you would put icons in Windows: by dragging a file to the "Desktop" directory in your home folder. If you want to add a program, right-click the desktop, then add a launcher by typing in the program's command.