# How do I make "add icons to the desktop" work in 10.04?

Tags: gnome, icons, settings

This question is closely related to other two questions: "[How to Add a Shortcut On Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44678/how-to-add-a-shortcut-on-desktop)" and "[How do I add icons to the desktop in 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97807/how-do-i-add-icons-to-the-desktop-in-10-04)" (this being a closed question). And I **know** the answers mentioned there! The problem is **it is not working**.

I just made a fresh Ubuntu 10.04 install a couple of days ago. Everything works fine for the main user: I can paste anything to the desktop, and it just works.

But I have created another user - as simple as it can be (no special settings; I just created a non-admin user and set its password).

Then, I logged in using this other user account. I just want to create a link for a "Games" folder, for my son, and I simply can't! It doesn't accept "paste", and the right button mouse click does nothing.

I have made several Ubuntu installations, several user accounts, and this never happened to me before! I tried to search some configuration/setting to fix it, but found nothing.
I had to use the "Preferences" menu to be able to change the background/wallpaper image.

If I paste files / folders / links to the "Desktop" file system folder, it works (i.e., the files are copied / moved to the "Desktop" folder), *but nothing appears in the desktop screen*!

And, what impressed me most, I found nothing searching on Google and Ask Ubuntu - I thought this would be a common issue... has anybody experienced this? Any clue to make the desktop just working normally?

Remembering: all works fine for the first user (the admin user created when installing the system).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable showing the desktop? As your regular user that is missing the shortcuts, run gconf-editor. Then navigate to Apps -> nautilus -> preferences and toggle the show_desktop option.

Also, make sure your regular user owns his desktop folder. i.e.

```
sudo chown -R regularuser:regularuser /home/regularuser/Desktop
```

Comment: Well... this is very crazy. I have **not** disabled showing the desktop **and** by using the gconf-editor app, the "show_desktop" option was appearing "checked". But, by unchecking it and then checking it back again, then the missing "Games" shorcut appeared in the desktop, which started "working" as I wanted. Problem seems to be solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Really solved! I restarted the computer, and the icon remains there, as it should. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked. I have seen that happen a lot (regardless of OS or application) where something gets mucked up and unsetting/resetting an option causes it to actually set the setting.